# Storing User Responses in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django, so I'm completely lost on some things that probably shouldn't be too hard, and I need someone to point me in the right direction. I'm working on a school project where we suggest Wikipedia articles for users based on how they rated previous articles. I'm trying to make a UI that will give the user an article, ask them to rate it from 1 to 5, send all of the users responses to another function, and then have this function spit out a new Wikipedia page id. The piece of this that's causing me the most trouble is figuring out how to keep track of all of the responses from each user to send as input for the other function. I looked online and couldn't find any easy way to store an ever changing dictionary of user information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using a database? With django it is pretty easy to create a database. First you will need to define a model in models.py of you app. Define two different models (this relates to tables in Database). say for example:

```
from django.db import models
class AppUser(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()

class WikiPage(models.Model):
  page_url = models.TextField()
  category = models.TextField() #this field can be used to suggest new wiki pages
  feeling = models.TextField() #This field can be used to suggest new wiki pages.

class WikiPageRating(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser)
  wiki = models.ForeighKey(WikiPage)
  rating = models.IntegerField() #Save your ratings here.
```

Next Under your views.py for your app, create the function that looks at all the users ratings and use your algorithm to spit out a new suggestion.

```
from yourapp.models import WikiPageRating
def spit_out_wiki_suggestion(user):
  past_ratings = WikiPageRating.objects.filter(user = user)
  #Use the Past Ratings to figure out how to pick wiki.
  #return the wikipedia page suggestion.

  return wikipediapage
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This definitely helps. I think I hadn't truly grasped the usefulness of models.